# Using group_modify with selected columns (retaining whole data frame and order)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have run out of R power on this one. I appreciate any help, it is probably quite simple for someone with more experience.

I have a data frame (tibble) with some numerical columns, a group column, and some other columns with other information. I want to do operations on the numerical columns, by group, but still retain all the columns.

I've put an example below: I am replacing the NAs with the group mean, for each column. The columns to replace the NAs are specified by the df_names variable.

It basically works, except it removes all columns except the numerical ones, AND reorders everything. Which makes it hard to reassemble. I could work around this, but I have a feeling there must be a simpler way to direct group_apply to specified columns, while retaining the other columns, and keeping the order.

Can anyone help? Thanks so much in advance!

Will

```
library("tidyverse")

# create tibble
df <- tibble(
  name=letters[1:10],
  csize=c("L","S","S","L","L","S","L","S","L","S"),
  v1=rnorm(10),
  v2=rnorm(10),
  v3=rnorm(10)
  )

# introduce some missing data
df$v1[3] <- NA
df$v1[6] <- NA
df$v1[7] <- NA
df$v3[2] <- NA

# these are the cols where I want to replace the NAs
df_names <- c("v1","v2","v3")

# this is the grouping variable (has to be stored as a string, since it is an input to the function)
groupvar <- "csize"

# now I want to replace the NAs with column means, restricted to their group
# the following line works, but the problem is that it removes the name column, and reorders the rows...
df_imp <- df %>% group_by(.dots=groupvar) %>% select(df_names) %>% group_modify( ~{replace_na(.x,as.list(colMeans(.x, na.rm=TRUE)))})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_modify` is overkill in this case; `mutate(across())` is your friend here:

```r
df %>% group_by(.dots = groupvar) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(df_names), ~if_else(is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x)))
```

Result:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   csize [2]
   name  csize     v1      v2      v3
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 a     L     -1.22   1.48   -0.628 
 2 b     S     -1.17   0.0890 -0.130 
 3 c     S     -0.422 -0.0956 -0.0271
 4 d     L     -0.265  0.180  -0.786 
 5 e     L     -0.491  0.509  -0.359 
 6 f     S     -0.422 -0.712   0.232 
 7 g     L     -0.400 -1.13    1.13  
 8 h     S     -0.538 -0.0785  0.690 
 9 i     L      0.373  0.308   0.252 
10 j     S      0.445  0.743  -1.41
```

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(csize) %>% mutate(across(v1:v3, ~ replace_na(., mean(., na.rm = T))))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   csize [2]
   name  csize     v1      v2     v3
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 a     L      1.57   0.310  -1.76 
 2 b     S     -0.705  0.0655  0.577
 3 c     S     -1.05   1.28    1.82 
 4 d     L      0.958 -2.09   -0.371
 5 e     L     -0.712  0.247  -1.13 
 6 f     S     -1.05  -0.516  -0.107
 7 g     L      0.403  1.79    0.128
 8 h     S     -0.793  1.52    1.07 
 9 i     L     -0.206 -0.369  -1.77 
10 j     S     -1.65  -0.992  -0.476
```